# What does the 10 flash signal indicate on my garage door opener?

Tags: doors, garage

My garage door opener will not close , I get the 10 flashing light signal. I have eliminated the sensors as the culprit by releasing the the door by pulling the red rope and when i push the button to engage the opener it works properly and even stops when i block the sensors. When i hook the door back up it trips and will not close and sends the 10 flashing lights. The door moves freely and there are no bad rollers. Why am i experiencing this ?

Comment: It would help if you posted the model number (or better, manual) of the opener. It may need you to re-run the initial setup after removing the power.

Comment: Guess: the close-force adjustment is wrong.

Comment: ... perhaps your opener is [signaling its alien overlords](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVciM0KVk4w)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://chamberlain.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2713/~/why-do-the-lights-on-my-garage-door-opener-flash-and-my-door-will-not-close%3F), 10 flashes means the door sensors have detected an obstacle.

> When properly connected and aligned, the sensor will detect an obstacle in the path of its electronic beam. If an obstruction breaks the light beam while the door is closing, the door will stop and reverse to full open position, and the opener lights will flash 10 times

Depending on the make and model of your opener, this may be what's causing your problem.

Depending on the sensors, there might be lights on the sensors. Check the manufacturer's documentation to determine what the color and/or status of the lights should be.